# Using Javascript to create element, then assign onclick to call pikadate

Tags: javascript, html, function, dynamic, onclick

First time poster, long time forager.  I have a system I am developing, cleaning up the process I would like to use pikaday.js to help users select the date insted of typing it in by hand.

The process:
From a dropdown (HTML) element, call to handleSelection(choice).  handleSelection then looks at the option selected and either creates an input or a second select element with options. For two of the options I would like to create an input and add an onclick to kick pikadate...All I am getting is a input field with no call to the function on click, I can type in the date in the correct format and get a result so the post portion is working.

See code as follows:

JavaScript protion:

```
<script src='moment.js></script> <----used for date format only
<script src='pikaday.js></script>
<script>
 function handleSelection(choice)
{
     if(choice=='ordnum' || choice=='po' || choice=='serial' || choice=='asset') <----Works as intended
     {
       var a=document.getElementById('input');
       var input=document.createElement('input');
       input.type='text';
       input.name='value';
       a.appendChild(input);
     }
      if(choice=='varified')<----Works as intended
    {
            var a=document.getElementById('valid');
            var valid=document.createElement('select');
            valid.name='value';
            valid.innerHTML="<option value='y'>Validated</option><option value='n'>Not Validated</option>";
            a.appendChild(valid);
    }
    if(choice=='loc')<----Works as intended
    {
            var a=document.getElementById('valid');
            var valid=document.createElement('select');
            valid.name='value';
            valid.innerHTML="<option value='loc0'>loc0</option><option value='loc1'>loc1</option><option value='loc2'>loc2</options><option value='loc3'>loc3</option><option value='loc4'>loc4</option><option value=';loc5'>loc5</option>";
            a.appendChild(valid);
    }

     if(choice=='drcv' || choice=='disrv') <---Isn't working as intended!
     {
        var a=document.getElementById('input');
        var input=document.createElement('input');
        input.type='text';
        input.name='value';
        input.id='pkr';
        input.onclick='getDate()'; <----Tried with quotes and with out, will not call out to getDate()
        a.appendChild(input);
     }
}
<script>
    function getDate()
    {
       var picker = new Pikaday({field:docuemnt.getElementById('pkr'),format:'YYYYMMDD'});
</script>
     }
}
</script>
```

HTML portion:

```
<body>
     <form class='container' name='report' action='somepage' method='post'>
        <select id='select' onChange='handleSelection(value)' name='opt'>
              <option value="ordnum">Order Number</option>
                            <option value="po">Po Number</option>
                            <option value="drecv">Date Received</option>
                            <option value="disrv">Date In Service</option>
                            <option value='serial'>Serial Number</option>
                            <option value='asset'>Asset Tag</option>
                            <option value='loc'>Location</option>
                            <option value='varified'>Verified</option>
                            <option value='*' selected>All Systems</option>
                    </select>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Fetch..">

                     </p>
                    <p id='input'>

            </p>
                    <p id='valid'>
            </p>

            </form>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So playing around a bit, seems style was the issue.  I had a div style set in my original CSS and it seems that the div in the pikaday.css was going off of that position causing the stretched effect.  I adjusted the percentage of the div in pickaday.css to 55% and now have the full effect that was wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
input.onclick='getDate()';
```

with

```
input.addEventListener('click', getDate, false);
```

you could also use `input.onclick = getDate;`, but addEventListener is the preferred way of adding event listeners.

And make sure the `getDate` function is in scope, that means that it's either inside the same script tag as the event listener, or a script tag above the one containing the event listener.
Hoisting doesn't help across script tags.

Comment: Thanks,  it brings up the picker but in a strange broken/separated manner and functionality of the picker is null, it will not enter the selected date into the input field.

Comment: That sounds like it's related to the plugin, and it's not something I can answer. Try setting up an example in JSFiddle and narrowing down the issue, and ask a new question specifically about the plugin, maybe someone knows it and can help you out.